# How to Open a pdf file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pdf

i am trying to open a pdf file in angularjs.actually i created a pdf file with database content and stored in the server location now i need to open a pdf file in the browser.I tried the bellow code.but not worked.

**controller.js**

```
$http.get(urlBase+'/generatePdfUrl')
      .success(function (data) {     // data is your url

          var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});

          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

          $window.open(fileURL);

      }).error(function(data){

          alert(data);
      });
```

I am getting my file URL correctly in data.but new tab open in the browser shows the below URL in browser address bar

**blob:http://localhost:8080/c87ffb9f-b2cb-8741-a2d2-3c8af5609359**

can any one help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(urlBase+'/generatePdfUrl').then(function(data){
        $window.open(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.